# Successive SelectMany in Linq Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have three tables built with EF code first.
I try to retrieve some information with SelectMany so that I can flatten the query and get only the fields that I need among those three tables.
My tables are presented as follow:

---

Tables: ProductOptions *-* ProductOptionValues 1-* LanguageProductOptionValue

---

```
    |ProductOptionID  |  OVPriceOffset        |  LanguagesListID
    |PriceOffset      |  OptionValueCategory  | ProductOptionValueName
    |                 |   ...                 |
```

---

```
var queryCabColor = _db.ProductOptions
             .Where(c => c.ProductOptionTypeID == 18 && c.ProductId == 1)
             .SelectMany(z => z.ProductOptionValues, (productOptions, productOptionValues)
             => new
             {
                 productOptions.ProductOptionID,
                 productOptions.PriceOffset,
                 productOptionValues.OVPriceOffset,
                 productOptionValues.OptionValueCategory,
                 productOptionValues.ProductOptionValuesID,
                 productOptionValues.Value,
                 productOptionValues.LanguageProductOptionValue
             })
             .SelectMany(d => d.LanguageProductOptionValue, (productOptionValues, productOptionValuesTranslation)
             => new
             {
                 productOptionValuesTranslation.LanguagesListID,
                 productOptionValuesTranslation.ProductOptionValueName
             })
             .Where(y => y.LanguagesListID == currentCulture);
```

So far, when I loop in the query I can just retrieve the LanguagesListID and ProductOptionValueName and I can't find a way to get all of the above mentionned fields. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case the Linq syntax is more appropriate than explicit `SelectMany`. Something like this should work:

```
var queryCabColor = 
    from productOptions in db.ProductOptions
    where productOptions.ProductOptionTypeID == 18 && productOptions.ProductId == 1
    from productOptionValues in productOptions.ProductOptionValues
    from productOptionValuesTranslation in productOptionValues.LanguageProductOptionValue
    where productOptionValuesTranslation.LanguagesListID == currentCulture
    select new
    {
         productOptions.ProductOptionID,
         productOptions.PriceOffset,
         productOptionValues.OVPriceOffset,
         productOptionValues.OptionValueCategory,
         productOptionValues.ProductOptionValuesID,
         productOptionValues.Value,
         productOptionValuesTranslation.LanguagesListID,
         productOptionValuesTranslation.ProductOptionValueName
    };
```